# LEFT OUTER JOIN NO DATAFRAME COM PANDAS

Tags: python, pandas, join, dataframe

**JÁ SANEI MINHA DÚVIDA, E DESCOBRI QUE POSSUE CAMPOS UC'S REPETIDOS NA BASE DE DADOS, porém segue abaixo quem quiser ler a pergunta e resolução:**

**Estou tentando receber depois da união de 2 dataframes, somente as linhas que possuem no df de acordo com o número da coluna 'UC'; (códigos seguem abaixo das informações)**

- Estou usando a biblioteca Pandas (python) e o jupyter;
- Vamos supor que o ARQUIVO DO USUÁRIO possui 20.000 linhas de informação;
- E a BASE DE DADOS possui 50.000 linhas de informação (df_data);
- Assim que recebo o arquivo do usuário para tratar os dados, transformo em dataframe (df) e faço com que ele receba o valor da 'UC' atualizado na junção dos 2dataframes, com o comando left, para assim retornar somente os valores que tem no df1, no caso eu espero o retorno de 20.000 linhas de informação;
- Porém eu recebo mais que 20.000 linhas;

**SEGUE ABAIXO O CÓDIGO**

> RECEBE O ARQUIVO, E OBTÉM ALGUMAS INFORMAÇÕES

```py
abriu = False
while not abriu:
    nome_do_arquivo = input("Digite o nome do arquivo de dados: ")
    
    try: 
        arquivo = open(nome_do_arquivo + ".txt", 'r') 
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print(nome_do_arquivo, " não encontrado. Você digitou direito?\n")
    else:
        abriu = True
        
print(f"Conteúdo do arquivo '{nome_do_arquivo}' logo abaixo!\n")

aux = 0
for linha in arquivo:
    print('Existe informação no arquivo!')
    break

count = 0
conteudo = arquivo.readlines() 
for i in conteudo:  
        count += 1

print("\nNúmero de linhas no arquivo:", count,".")
```

> FUNÇÃO DE TRATAR OS DADOS (retira os espaços)

```py
def treatdata(a):
    #print(a)
    uc = a[0:9]
    valor = ''
    titular = a[9:79]
    logradouro = a[79:122]
    numero = a[122:132]
    complemento = a[132:172]
    info = (uc, valor, titular.rstrip(), logradouro.rstrip(), numero.rstrip(), complemento.rstrip())
    #print(info)
    return info
```

> CHAMA A FUNÇÃO DE TRATAR OS DADOS

- no caso eu usei 20.000 linhas como exemplo, porém o count serve para ler a quantidade de linhas que possui o arquivo;

```py
import pandas as pd
with open("arquivo.txt", "r") as arquivo:
    aux = 0
    aux1 = 0
    if aux == 0:
        df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['UC', 'Valor', 'Titular', 'Logradouro', 'Número', 'Complemento'])
    for i in arquivo.readlines():
        if aux1 <= 20000: #count
            info = treatdata(i)
            df.loc[len(df)] = info
            print(i)
            aux1 = aux1 + 1
        else:
            break 
    display(df)
    arquivo.close()
```

[df(arquivo que recebi do usuário)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MWoOU.png)

> DATAFRAME DA BASE DE DADOS

```py
df_data = pd.read_csv("database.csv")
display(df_data)
#aqui usei como exemplo que ela tivesse 50.000 linhas, porém ela possui mais do que isso!
```

> JUNÇÃO DA BASE DE DADOS COM O DF1 E RETORNO DAS INFORMAÇÕES QUE CONSTAM SOMENTE NO DF1 DE ACORDO COM A 'UC'

```py
#união do dataframe do arquivo com o dataframe da base de dados;
df_cosipnew = df.merge(df_data, on=['UC'], how='left', suffixes=['_NEW','_BD'])
display(df_cosipnew)
```

- só que aqui na imagem ele retorna mais linhas que o df1 possui;

[uniãodabasedeadosedf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p82Xy.png)

- A princípio como consigo retornar somente a quantidade de linhas que tenho df?
- criei 2 arquivos csv(simulando os dados e com eles já no formato que eu quero, então não vai precisar tratar ele),sendo 1 o df e outro df_data, repeti as uc's no df_data, segue:
- detalhe importante: o campo logradouro e número (header das colunas), foi trocado pelo campo endereço no arquivo, então tem que editar no código!

[df_data](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Q4pfKjwiEmTyVMFej-FFVUDwfVd4CuxM/view?usp=share_link)
[df](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vtX5NinevYz39pjocnGl69-6kO2VJQs3/view?usp=share_link)

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Sem os dados fica difícil verificar o problema. Porém, acredito que com o exemplo abaixo, você consiga verificar.

**Criando o primeiro dataframe**

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"UF": ["RJ", "SP", "RS", "BA"], "VAL": [1, 2, 3, 4]})

df1
   UF  VAL
0  RJ    1
1  SP    2
2  RS    3
3  BA    4
```

**Criando o segundo dataframe**

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"UF": ["RJ", "SP", "RS", "MG", "RE"], "VAL": [5, 6, 7, 8, 9]})

df2
   UF  VAL
0  RJ    5
1  SP    6
2  RS    7
3  MG    8
4  RE    9
```

**Merge usando `left`**

```
pd.merge(df1, df2, on=['UF'], how='left', suffixes=['_df1','_df2'])

   UF  VAL_df1  VAL_df2
0  RJ        1      5.0
1  SP        2      6.0
2  RS        3      7.0
3  BA        4      NaN
```

**Nota**: Somente as UFs que existe no **df1** irão aparecer no resultado

**Merge usando `inner`**

```
pd.merge(df1, df2, on=['UF'], how='inner', suffixes=['_df1','_df2'])

   UF  VAL_df1  VAL_df2
0  RJ        1        5
1  SP        2        6
2  RS        3        7
```

**Nota**: Somente as UFs que aparecerem nos **DOIS** dataframes irão para o resultado

**Merge usando `right`**

```
pd.merge(df1, df2, on=['UF'], how='right', suffixes=['_df1','_df2'])

   UF  VAL_df1  VAL_df2
0  RJ      1.0        5
1  SP      2.0        6
2  RS      3.0        7
3  MG      NaN        8
4  RE      NaN        9
```

**Nota**: Somente as UFs que existirem no **df2** farão parte do resultado.

### Atualizado

O resultado obtido por você deve se dar ao fato do seu dataframe da direita possuir "UC" repetidas.

Veja o exemplo abaixo:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"UF": ["RJ", "SP", "RS", "BA"], "VAL": [1, 2, 3, 4]})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({"UF": ["RJ", "SP", "RS", "MG", "RE", "RJ", "RJ"], "VAL": [6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]})

pd.merge(df1, df2, on=['UF'], how='left', suffixes=['_df1','_df2'])

   UF  VAL_df1  VAL_df2
0  RJ        1      6.0
1  RJ        1     11.0
2  RJ        1     12.0
3  SP        2      7.0
4  RS        3      8.0
5  BA        4      NaN
```

Perceba que RJ se repete, pois o mesmo aparece 3 vezes no dataframe da direita (df2). Com isso o resultado possui 5 linhas, enquanto df1 apenas 4.

Comment: Desculpe Paulo por não fornecer os arquivos, é que eles possuem dados pessoais dos cidadãos que residem no município em que trabalho! 
Obrigada pela resposta, e já estou utilizando o 'left' no código, porém ele retorna mais linhas do que deveria, já usei o 'drop_duplicates', mas ainda continua  a possuir mais linhas do que deveria!

Comment: @IzaCaroline, melhor atualizar seu post com dados fictícios que permitam a reprodutibilidade do problema. E também corrigir o `df` e `df1`, pois você descreve `df1` quando sua variável é `df`

Comment: Certo vou aderir, obrigada :)

Comment: Isso mesmo Paulo, tem UC's na base de dados repetidas; 
- criei os arquivos de simulação também, só quem sem os campos logradouro e número, e sim o campo endereço;
- peguei essa base de dados de outro funcionário, vou ver como posso arrumar aqui;
- Muito Obrigada pela ajuda, vai ser difícil, mas não impossível haha, ainda mais 90.000 linhas de base de dados.